Flatlist needing time before it can scroll
I have a Pressable, which "opens" up using an Animated View, and in this view I want to show a FlatList. I use this component in two files, club.tsx and PbTable.tsx. In PbTable.tsx this works flawlessly, but on the one rendered in club.tsx I can't scroll. It is probably happening because of a parent, but I just can't find where. Sometimes, if I wait a little while, I can scroll, but if I then lift my finger I need to wait a little while again.
club.tsx:
<Page>
      <View
        style={{
          minHeight: "83%",
          display: "flex",
          justifyContent: "center",
          alignItems: "center",
        }}
      >
        <SchemaComponent colorScheme={colorScheme} schema={schema} />
        <WedstrijdenComponent
          colorScheme={colorScheme}
          wedstrijden={wedstrijden}
        />
        <ClubrecordComponent
          clubrecords={clubrecords}
          colorScheme={colorScheme}
        />
      </View>
    </Page>

ClubrecordComponent:
<Pressable
      style={{
        width: Dimensions.get("window").width,
        borderColor: "#ef8b22",
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderRadius: 6,
        paddingVertical: 10,
        paddingHorizontal: 20,
        overflow: "hidden",
        marginVertical: 10,
      }}
      onPress={toggleExpand}
    >
      <View
        style={{
          flexDirection: "row",
          alignItems: "center",
          justifyContent: "space-between",
        }}
      >
        <Text
          style={{ ...textColor(colorScheme), textTransform: "capitalize" }}
        >
          Clubrecords
        </Text>
        <Animated.View style={{ transform: [{ rotate }] }}>
          <FontAwesome
            name="arrow-right"
            size={15}
            color={colorScheme === "dark" ? "#fff" : "#000"}
          />
        </Animated.View>
      </View>
      <Animated.View
        style={{
          maxHeight: heightAnim.interpolate({
            inputRange: [0, 1],
            outputRange: [0, 1000],
          }),
          opacity: heightAnim,
          marginTop: heightAnim.interpolate({
            inputRange: [0, 1],
            outputRange: [0, 10],
          }),
        }}
      >
        <FlatList
          data={clubrecords.male}
          style={{ height: 350 }}
          scrollEnabled={true}
          renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
            <Text key={index} style={textColor(colorScheme)}>
              {item.distance} {item.event}
            </Text>
          )}
          onScroll={() => console.log("scrolling")}
        />
      </Animated.View>
    </Pressable>

PbTable:
<Fragment>
      <QuickViewModal
        athleteData={athleteData}
        colorScheme={colorScheme}
        loading={loading}
        onPressChoose={async () => {
          setLoading(true);
          const id =
            SwimrakingEventId[title.distance as keyof typeof SwimrakingEventId];
          const data = await getHistory(id, athleteData.id, title.poolSize);
          setHistoryModalShown(id);
          setSData(data);
          setQuickViewModalShown(false);
          setLoading(false);
        }}
        onPressClose={() => setQuickViewModalShown(false)}
        onRequestClose={() => setQuickViewModalShown(false)}
        title={title}
        visible={quickViewModalShown}
      />
      <HistoryModal
        colorScheme={colorScheme}
        onPressClose={() => setHistoryModalShown(SwimrakingEventId.None)}
        sData={sData}
        title={title}
        visible={historyModalShown !== SwimrakingEventId.None}
        onRequestClose={() => {
          setHistoryModalShown(SwimrakingEventId.None);
          setQuickViewModalShown(true);
        }}
      />
      <View
        style={{
          minHeight: "83%",
          display: "flex",
          justifyContent: "center",
          alignItems: "center",
        }}
      >
        {Object.keys(strokes).map((stroke) => (
          <StrokeComponent
            stroke={stroke as keyof typeof Strokes}
            strokeData={strokes[stroke as keyof typeof Strokes]}
            key={stroke}
            onItemPress={(item) => {
              setTitle(item.title);
              setQuickViewModalShown(true);
            }}
          />
        ))}
      </View>
    </Fragment>

StrokeComponent:
<Pressable
      style={{
        width: Dimensions.get("window").width,
        borderColor: "#ef8b22",
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderRadius: 6,
        paddingVertical: 10,
        paddingHorizontal: 20,
        overflow: "hidden",
        marginVertical: 10,
      }}
      onPress={toggleExpand}
    >
      <View
        style={{
          flexDirection: "row",
          alignItems: "center",
          justifyContent: "space-between",
        }}
      >
        <Text
          style={{ ...textColor(colorScheme), textTransform: "capitalize" }}
        >
          {stroke}
        </Text>
        <Animated.View style={{ transform: [{ rotate }] }}>
          <FontAwesome
            name="arrow-right"
            size={15}
            color={colorScheme === "dark" ? "#fff" : "#000"}
          />
        </Animated.View>
      </View>
      <Animated.View
        style={{
          maxHeight: heightAnim.interpolate({
            inputRange: [0, 1],
            outputRange: [0, 1000],
          }),
          opacity: heightAnim,
          marginTop: heightAnim.interpolate({
            inputRange: [0, 1],
            outputRange: [0, 10],
          }),
        }}
      >
        <FlatList
          data={strokeData}
          style={{ height: 350 }}
          renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
            <Pressable
              key={index}
              style={{
                paddingHorizontal: 10,
                paddingVertical: 5,
                borderColor: "grey",
                borderWidth: 1,
                borderRadius: 6,
                marginVertical: 5,
                flexDirection: "row",
              }}
              onPress={(e) => (onItemPress ? onItemPress(item, e) : null)}
            >
              <Text
                style={{
                  ...textColor(colorScheme),
                  flex: 1,
                  textAlign: "left",
                }}
              >
                {item.title.distance}
              </Text>
              <Text
                style={{
                  ...textColor(colorScheme),
                  flex: 1,
                  textAlign: "center",
                }}
              >
                {item.title.time}
              </Text>
              <Text
                style={{
                  ...textColor(colorScheme),
                  flex: 1,
                  textAlign: "right",
                }}
              >
                {item.title.poolSize}
              </Text>
            </Pressable>
          )}
        />
      </Animated.View>
    </Pressable>

Implementation of PbTable:
<Page>
{/*... other component, next to the PbTable*/}
{activeTab === Tabs.Pbs && (
            <PbTable
              top={0}
              data={athleteData.pbs.map((pb) => {
                return {
                  key: `${pb.event} - ${pb.poolSize} - ${pb.date}`,
                  title: {
                    distance: pb.event,
                    poolSize: pb.poolSize,
                    time: pb.time,
                  },
                  id: SwimrakingEventId[
                    pb.event as keyof typeof SwimrakingEventId
                  ],
                };
              })}
              athleteData={athleteData}
            />
          )}


Even coppying the layout from the working code into a test file doesnt seem to work

I have solved it. I created an external component and copied over the code for the one that worked, and somehow it worked now.
If you run into the same issue as me, here is how is the component that works (for me):
https://github.com/larsdekooter/TeamBBZ/blob/master/components/SectionComponent.tsx
